# How to change widget configuration at runtime for custom backoffice extension?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to change widget configuration at runtime based on the user. I would like to populate the collection-browser with different sub types of promotions (this is a custom type for my requirement). For certain users they should only see certain promotion types and be able to add/delete these types.

```
<widget id="custombackoffice-search-init"
        widgetDefinitionId="com.hybris.cockpitng.widgets.common.propextractor"
        template="false" slotId="cockpitWidgetChildrenInvisible">
    <setting key="expression">'Promotion'</setting>
    <setting key="socketDataType_$T" type="String">java.lang.String</setting>
</widget>

<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="custombackoffice-search-init" outputId="genericOutput"
                   targetWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-fulltextsearch" inputId="type"/>
<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-fulltextsearch" outputId="searchData"
                   targetWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-advancedsearchengine" inputId="searchData"/>
<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-fulltextsearch" outputId="searchContextChanged"
                   targetWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-advancedsearchengine" inputId="changeSearchContext"/>
<widget-connection sourceWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-advancedsearchengine" outputId="pageable"
                   targetWidgetId="custombackoffice-collectionBrowser-browser" inputId="pageable"/>
```

Is there a way to configure the type `'Promotion'` to have a different subtype at runtime or have different configurations configured beforehand for each user. I know I can restrict the data with searchRestrictions but using only search restrictions impacts the *backoffice-listviewactions. These actions are only visible if a user has read/write access on the configured type e.g. 'Promotion'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8b6f8af58669101495a7aa8620585384.html) . In case you need any more answers about backoffice widgets, [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8c17194286691014a193a36c8507ba79.html?q=pop%20up%20widget#loiocfde32520c1a427f85e917b1b66e9775) is a good documentation with a lot of questions with answers provided by SAP.